# Data format on Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

I'm starting to learn about Laravel Framework and I have a little doubt.

I have 2 models: Customers and Opportunities.
I want to display on opportunities/show.blade.php the customer name but I have a problem with the format of the data I retrieve from customer table on the controller.

I have this show function on my OpportunityController:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $opportunity = Opportunity::find($id);

    $customerName = Customer::select('name')->where('id','=',$opportunity->customer_id)->first();

    return view('opportunities.show',compact('opportunity','customerName'));
}
```

And i call this variable on the show.blade.php like this:

```
{{ $customerName }}
```

But it's showing the customer name on this format:

```
Customer: {"name":"John"}
```

How can I show the customer name as this:

```
Customer: John
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data return by a model is a `Std Class Object`, so you can use it like:

```
{{ $customerName->name }}  // i.e. variable->column_name
```

It will print `John`.

If the you are using `get()` instead of `first()` then you have to iterate the returned `array` of `Std Class Object` variable by using `foreach()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently returning a Model Object. So, you have to specify the attribute you wish to display. In your case, you selected only the name. So, do this:

```
{{ $customerName->name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query selects a single row from the database, but it is still returned as an object:

`Customer::select('name')->where('id','=',$opportunity->customer_id)->first();`

So the result of the query will be an object that translates to `{"name":"John"}`

If you want the name value you can either use `{{ $customerName->name }}` in your view or change the query to the following to get only the `name` column:

`Customer::select('name')->where('id','=',$opportunity->customer_id)->first()->name;`

Answer (score 0):

`$customerName` is treated as an object in this case so please try `{{ $customerName->name }}` for getting a value of `name` .

Hope it can help you